# Does the django-rest-framework provide an admin site to manage models?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm looking to setup a REST API server with django, and googling suggests this is best done using the [django-rest-framework](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/).

The API will return objects stored in a database, and I would also like to be able to add/modify the objects in the database using the [django admin site](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/admin/). However, looking at the django-rest-framework documentaion, I see no reference to the admin site (I did find things about "AdminRenderer", but it looked like this isn't what I want).

Simply, does the django admin site exist for a django-rest-framework project?

Comment: Why don't you just use Django admin itself?

Answer (score 4):

Simply use the django admin panel provided by django:

Step 1: create superuser

```
python manage.py createsuperuser
```

Step 2: run server

```
python manage.py runserver
```

Setp 3: Enter the admin site with the newly created credientials

```
127.0.0.1:8000/admin
```

Learn more form official documentation:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/intro/tutorial02/#creating-an-admin-user

Answer (score 1):

Since around 2015 (version 3.2) there is an admin interface already available.

Just add it to your settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
'DEFAULT_RENDERER_CLASSES': [
    'rest_framework.renderers.JSONRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.AdminRenderer',
    'rest_framework.renderers.BrowsableAPIRenderer'
],
'DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS': 'rest_framework.pagination.PageNumberPagination',
'PAGE_SIZE': 100
}
```

More details:

[https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.2-announcement/#:~:text=to%20list%20behaviors-,Django%20REST%20framework%203.2,friendly%20interface%20to%20the%20API](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.2-announcement/#:%7E:text=to%20list%20behaviors-,Django%20REST%20framework%203.2,friendly%20interface%20to%20the%20API).

Answer (score 0):

you can also use the AdminRenderer of django-rest-framework for CRUD operations for using in this purpose as well.

https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#adminrenderer